# Найти и зменить длинное тире на минус

Tags: c, регулярные-выражения, распознавание-символов

Вот мой код

```c
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <cstring>

#define MAX_MATCHES 2 // Максимальное количество совпадений, которые мы ожидаем получить

int main() {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("weath.png");
    cv::Rect roi(500, 18, 350, 17); // left, top, width, height
    cv::Mat cropped_img = img(roi);
    cv::resize(cropped_img, cropped_img, cv::Size(cropped_img.size().width*3, cropped_img.size().height*3)); 
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    ocr->Init(NULL, "rus+eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    ocr->SetImage(cropped_img.data, cropped_img.size().width, cropped_img.size().height, cropped_img.channels(), cropped_img.step1());
    ocr->Recognize(0);
    char* text = ocr->GetUTF8Text();
    printf(" %s\n", text);

    char* minus_text = text;
    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (text[i] == 0x2013 || text[i] == 0x2014) {
            minus_text[i] = '-';
        }
    }
    printf(" %s\n", text);
    regex_t regexCompiled;
    regmatch_t groupArray[MAX_MATCHES];
    char* cursor = minus_text;
    if (regcomp(&regexCompiled, "-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED))
    {
        printf("Could not compile regular expression.\n");
        return 1;
    };

    char* extracted_floats[MAX_MATCHES];
    for (int m = 0; m < MAX_MATCHES; m++) {
        if (regexec(&regexCompiled, cursor, 1, groupArray, 0)) {
            break;  // No more matches
        }

        int length = groupArray[0].rm_eo - groupArray[0].rm_so;
        if (cursor[groupArray[0].rm_so] != '-') {  // If it's not negative
            // Allocate one extra char for '+'
            extracted_floats[m] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 2));
            strcpy(extracted_floats[m], "+");
            strncpy(extracted_floats[m] + 1, cursor + groupArray[0].rm_so, length);
            extracted_floats[m][length + 1] = '\0';
        } else {
            extracted_floats[m] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
            strncpy(extracted_floats[m], cursor + groupArray[0].rm_so, length);
            extracted_floats[m][length] = '\0';
        }
        cursor += groupArray[0].rm_eo;
    }

    printf("Найденные числа: %s, %s\n", extracted_floats[0], extracted_floats[1]);


    ocr->End();
    return 0;
}
```

вот картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
пробовал так же с таким фрагментом:

```c
std::string minus_text = std::string(text);
    std::replace(minus_text.begin(), minus_text.end(), L'—', L'-');

    regex_t regexCompiled;
    regmatch_t groupArray[MAX_MATCHES];
    char* cursor = text;
    if (regcomp(&regexCompiled, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED))
    {
        printf("Could not compile regular expression.\n");
        return 1;
    };
```

все равно выдает:

> —4.5 <= 546056 T Bryanskaya <= 16.68

> Найденные числа: +4.5, +16.68

Как побороть?
Спасибо!

Comment: char никогда не будет равен 0x2013.

Comment: длинное тире имеет код `UTF-16: 0x2013` и при конвертировании в utf-8 будет занимать три байта `UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0x93`. Вам не нужна эта конвертация. Искать надо в тексте оригинала.

Comment: @AlexGlebe
"Искать надо в тексте оригинала." я немного не понял, что вы имели ввиду.
Где искать? В распознанном?

Comment: ну не использовать `GetUTF8Text`, а искать функцию, которая возвращает указатель на строки `wchar_t *`. А этот тип `wchar_t` как раз и может содержать буквы 0x2013.